# Proof for uncertainty (resolution) of Short Time Fourier Transform

Tags: proof-explanation, fourier-transform

I'm looking for a proof for the uncertainty relation of the Short Time Fourier transform (STFT). I would be very pleased if someone has a literature / source recommendation for an understandable proof. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Here it is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-time_Fourier_transform

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply. The wikipedia article is rather an explanation for the resolution issues, but I'm looking for a proof to estimate the lower limit (at least I did not find it there)